# How do I connect multiple events to a single event handler in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, winforms, events, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to add multiple events to this event handler

```
private: System::Void lblColumn1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

I know in Visual Basic .Net its done like this

```
Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click, btnClickme.Click
```

but I cannot figure it out for C++/CLI

Any Idea ?

Comment: I found something like this `lblHB11->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &lblColumn1_Click);` but it does not work and comes with a couple errors

Comment: correction: you want to **handle** multiple events with that function..  which translates to, how do I add a **handle** of that function to multiple invocation lists ( aka Delegates, aka EventHandler(s)).

Comment: in the following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx, it states **You can use the delegate type to declare a variable that can refer to any method with the same signature as the delegate**.. in C++/CLI, that ref 'variable' is called a **handle**.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `this->lblHB15->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::lblHB16_Click);` where the label is created at the top where normally its own event would be

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to wire the save event handler to the `Click` event of distinct label controls. In Visual Studio, open the form in design mode, click on the label, open the **Properties** tab and go the the **Events** list. For the `Click` event, open the drop-down list and select the event handler you want to wire the event to.

You can also do all this manually:

```
label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label_Click);
label2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label_Click);

System::Void label_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
}
```